# Woocommerce REST API authentication with server password

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

There is a server with password protection (.htaccess). So, standard WooCommerce REST API authentication doesn't work with settings:

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
        'https://test.site.com',
        'ck_--------------',
        'cs_--------------',
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v1',
            'timeout' => 500,
        ]
    );
```

And I get an error:

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.

How can I authorize my application?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `Client` class coming from? It's certainly not from WordPress. You have to read its documentation to see how you can pass the credentials.